# Why doesnt confirmation box come up?

Tags: javascript, html

```
JavaScript 

function AdultNumber(){              /* Ticket Number Validation   */  
    var AdInput = parseInt($("#adult").val());    //Declare it as an Integer  
    var ChildInput = parseInt ($("#child").val());

    if (ChildInput >=0 && ChildInput <= 50  && AdInput > 0 && AdInput <= 50 || AdInput > 0 && AdInput <= 50 && !ChildInput   ){   //If passengers are between 0 to 10 
        document.getElementById("AdTickError").textContent = "";
        document.getElementById("ChildTickError").textContent = "";
        return true;

    }



   else if( AdInput >= 10 ) {  //If user input is greater than 10 
        confirm("Are you sure you want 10+ Passengers?");
        document.getElementById("AdTickError").textContent = "";
        return true;
    }

    else{
        document.getElementById("AdTickError").textContent = "Incorrect Enter Correct Number Of Passengers";

        return false;
    }


}

HTML: 

       <div class="main-wrapper">
        <Form action="#" class="group" name="form2" id="Form-2" method="post">
        <legend id="fixed"><span class="number">2</span>Tickets</legend> 
        <div class="half-col">
        <label for="Adult-ticket" class="center-label">Adults(+16)</label>
        <input type="number" id="adult" name="user_adult">
        <label id="AdTickError"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="half-col">
        <label for="child-ticket" class="center-label">Child</label>
        <input type="number" id="child" name="user_child">
        <label id="ChildTickError"></label>

        </div>
     <button type = "button" value="checkout" id="checkoutbtn" onclick="AdultNumber(); calculateFare(); " >CHECKOUT</button>
```

Why doesnt the confirmation box show up after choosing+10 for the number type input fields (Child) and (Adult) ID's? It should be displayed twice if choosing +10 for both boxes. Currently nothing happens. Plus would it be more appropiate if I chose alert box or confirmation box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement has a max for ChildInput and AdInput of 50 instead of 10. It's never hitting the else if statement which shows the alert boxes.

`if (ChildInput >=0 && ChildInput <= 50  && AdInput > 0 && AdInput <= 50 || AdInput > 0 && AdInput <= 50 && !ChildInput   ){   //If passengers are between 0 to 10 
        document.getElementById("AdTickError").textContent = "";`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, it would be easier with JQuery:

```
$('#checkoutbtn').on('click',function(){

    var AdInput = parseInt($("#adult").val());    //Declare it as an Integer  
    var ChildInput = parseInt ($("#child").val());

    if (ChildInput >=0 && ChildInput <= 50  && AdInput > 0 && AdInput <= 50 || AdInput > 0 && AdInput <= 50 && !ChildInput   ){   //If passengers are between 0 to 10 
        document.getElementById("AdTickError").textContent = "";
        document.getElementById("ChildTickError").textContent = "";
        return true;

    }

   else if( AdInput >= 10 || ChildInput>=10) {  //If user input is greater than 10 
        confirm("Are you sure you want 10+ Passengers?");
        document.getElementById("AdTickError").textContent = "";
        return true;
    }

    else{
        document.getElementById("AdTickError").textContent = "Incorrect Enter Correct Number Of Passengers";
        return false;
    }
});
```

Of course, remove the *"onclick"* actions on the HTML button tag.